# Create a TextBox in Plotly Python

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

Can I somehow make a report in `Plotly` where the left side will be a text, **which changes on a slider pick**, and the right side is my chart? The way without using `dash` and too much `javascript` is preferred.

It should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Have a look at: https://plot.ly/dash/getting-started-part-2 (chaining outputs)

Comment: @MaximilianPeters, thanks. Is there another way w/o using `dash`?

Comment: As far as I know, no, not in Python

Comment: Do you think this could help you out https://plot.ly/python/textbox-widget/?

Comment: @user32185, unfortunately, not so much but thanks for a link!

Comment: @rpanai Link is dead

Comment: @jtlz2 The library and its documentations quite a while over the past 2 years.

Answer (score 0):

For people still looking for an answer:

***Some plotly.graph_objects basics first:***

Plotly figure is made up of 3 parts: Data (trace to be plotted), Layout (on which data is to be plotted), Frame (Data + Layout to be used for looping)

To answer your question to include text on the left side you will have to write the text as a annotation (layout). To include two charts on right use subplots (data). To update them with slider pick you will have to update them with Frame. Each frame will have Data+Layout which corresponds to that slider position.

**Generic code flow:**

Let's assume:

1. Dataframe df has 4 columns X,Y1,Y2,Dates
2. Your slider represents different dates

```py
#Import plotly graph object
import plotly.graph_objects as go
      
#Getting different dates
dates = df['Dates'].unique().tolist()
    
#Plotting first instance
data=[]
#Fig 1
data_dict1 = {{
"x": list(df["X"]),
"y": list(df["Y1"]),
"type":"scatter"},
"ncol":2,"nrow":1 #Subplot location
}
#Fig 2
data_dict2 = {
"x": list(df["X"]),
"y": list(df["Y2"]),
"type":"scatter",
"ncol":2,"nrow":2 #Subplot location
}

data = [data_dict1,data_dict2] #combining both plots

#Layout and slider
layout = {
"sliders" : [{
#Enter required slider layout
 ,"steps": [] #should include this line in slider
}],
 "annotations":[ {
 #Input required annotations
 }]
} # layout ends
    
#making Frames
frames =[]
for date in dates:
    frame = {"data": [], "name": str(date),"layout":{"annotations":[]}} # Saving each data frame
    dataset = df[df[Dates]==date]  #subsetting data for a date
    # Create charts for this subset data
    #Fig 1
    data_dict1 = {{
    "x": list(dataset["X"]),
    "y": list(dataset["Y1"]),
    "type":"scatter"},
    "ncol":2,"nrow":1 #Subplot location
    }
    #Fig 2
    data_dict2 = {
    "x": list(dataset["X"]),
    "y": list(dataset["Y2"]),
    "type":"scatter",
    "ncol":2,"nrow":2 #Subplot location
    }
    
    #Adding this data to frame
    frame["data"] = [data_dict1,data_dict2]
    
    # Creating lines to be displayed using annotations
    annote1 = {
      #Add data for line 1 
    }
    annote2 = {
      #Add data for line 2 
    }
    annote3 = {
      #Add data for line 3 
    }
    annote4 = {
      #Add data for line 4 
    }
    
    #Adding all annotations lines to frame
    frame["layout"]["annotations"] = [annote1,annote2,annote3,annote4]
    
    #Combinig all frames    
    frames.append(frame)
    
    #Updating slider step
    slider_step = {
    "label": date,
    "method": "update"}
    #Adding step to layout slider
    layout["sliders"][0]["steps"].append(slider_step)
    
#Combine everything
fig = go.Figure(data =data,layout = layout, frames =frames)
#View in browser
plot(fig, auto_open=True)
```

Hope the logic flow is clear!